# How to find the uptime of the listed boots?

Tags: journalctl

The **sudo journalctl -k -b < hash>** lists the logs of the specific boot session. Is there a way to find the uptime of that session?. I want to find the uptime of a reboot session due to power failure.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but there's `last reboot` and the final column shown should be the uptime.

Comment: Thanks. This was the command I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of journald tracking uptime directly, but you can look at timestamps of 1st and last log message of the session (which is also summarized in 1st line of the `journalctl -b BOOT_ID` output), and estimate uptime based on that.